# git recover deleted file alongwith its change history

Tags: git

I have created a branch and then made 10 commits and pushed the code. In the first commit i have made lot of changes and also copied 4 files from directory `scraper/` to `scraper/utils` directory and removed the original files from scraper/.

What i did wrong is that i copied and deleted the files manually instead of using `git mv` due to which files lost their change history.

Now what i want is to get those files change history back.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is your new branch created from another branch? If those files existed in other branches before you can just simply check out the files from the parent commit of your first commit of the new branch. If they are completely new & not tracked by git before I don't see anyway you can recover from it.

Comment: Those files exists on branch from which i created my branch.

Comment: I checked out the delete file from parent commit of first commit of my branch but the deleted file is added as new file so there is not change history :(

Comment: I think the first commit may have prevented the history from being added back....do you have lots of development on those files after the first commit? If not you can do `git revert first_commit_sha1` and then do the `git mv` thing you mentioned above....that way you can build your changes up again if there are not too many (you can use `git cherry-pick ` for the following commits to reapply the other commits after the first one)

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use `git mv` to make Git track renames. You can just `mv` a file, or `rm` it and add the same (or very similar) file elsewhere in the working tree, and Git will still track this as a rename. You just need to `git add` the paths to both the deleted and the newly added files.